# Changing values in a hidden dynamic html form

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

I have a hidden form on my page that is being populated on click of a button dynamically. I want to change the values that it gets dynamically. So at first it is a basic form tag,

```
<form id="zakeke-addtocart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

but later if i log it with(catch the ajax request on the document)

```
let zakekeCart=jQuery('#zakeke-addtocart').serializeArray();
console.log("ZakekeFORM: "+JSON.stringify(zakekeCart));
```

i see that it has been populated:

```
[{"name":"attribute_pa_color","value":"blue"},{"name":"addon-659-typ-0","value":"three-3"},{"name":"addon-659-lib-1","value":"dos-2"},{"name":"quantity","value":"1"},{"name":"yith-wacp-is-excluded","value":"yes"},{"name":"zakeke_design","value":"000-aog2vpBJLU6QAOorpYFc3w"},{"name":"add-to-cart","value":"659"},{"name":"product_id","value":"659"},{"name":"zakeke_model","value":"112583"}]
```

Supposing that i know all the "name" s like addon-659 or quantity, how can i grab them and change the values connected to them. I can grab the request with ajax i guess, but how do i grab each key value pair to change them,meaning change them IN the form so my values get forwarded with the post of the form?

Comment: did you tried with `$("input[name='yourinputname']").val('yournewvalue')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change their `value` property:

```
formElement.value = "some value"
```

Comment: normally yes, but how do i get the element if i only know whats been logged? Theres no id just some "name" which doesnt seem to work with getElementsByName either.

Comment: If it is a name attribute, use: `document.querySelector("elementTagName[name=valueOfNameAttribute]")`